# Where is the most knowledgeable Abhidhamma Community?

Tags: theravada, monk, abhidhamma, visuddhimagga, commentary

Who are the most knowledgeable Abhidhamma masters today? Where are the active Abhidhamma communities?

- country
- lineage
- monastery
- institute
- teacher
- group
- website
- forum

Answer (score 2):

[*Ven. Bhikkhu Bodhi*](https://www.baus.org/en/teaching/bhikkhu-bodhi/) is highly skilled and experienced in teaching the Abhidhamma. He's my go-to-source for Abhidhamma material and teachings.

He made several [*Abhidhamma Study Retreats that can all be watched on Youtube*](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=abhidhamma%20study%20retreat%20bhikkhu%20bodhi) and the book "[*Comprehensive Manual of Abhidhamma"*](https://www.saraniya.com/books/meditation/Bhikkhu_Bodhi-Comprehensive_Manual_of_Abhidhamma.pdf).

May this be of use to you.

Comment: He is praised for his scholarship but somewhat looked down by classical abhidhamma masters because his writing style and foot-notes indirectly arouse doubts about Abhidhamma itself.

Comment: I don't agree on that. I think he is one of the best Abhidhamma teachers to this day.